# htccess redirect all .php?123 to another url

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to redirect all urls with .php? to only .php ?

I´m using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+\.php)/.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?secure/(.*) https://example.org$1 [R,L]
```

How can i prevent somone using urls that doesn´t exist on my server?

It´s all about blocking everything that comes after .php like ?123456789

Answer (score 0):

Why should it be an issue if someone adds a query string to a URL? Unless your php scripts react to that, of course, but that is something you can control, can't you?

Nevertheless it certainly is possible to drop such query strings if you want to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule \.php$ %{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=301,L]
```

For this to work the apache rewrite module needs to be loaded into the http server, obviously.

It is a good diea to start with a `R=302` *temporary* redirection first. And to only change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as desired. That prevents nasty caching issues for your users.

You should prefer to implement such rules in the actual http server's host configuration. If you have no access to that you can also use a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"), but that comes with a few disadvantages. And has to be enabled first.

Comment: Thank you @Arkascha This solution works. I´m  doing this because i run a travel blog and people read about my trips.Google is now indexing urls with querystrings wich never was mentioned to exist because it´s all the same page with same post/content.This causes duplicated content , wich harms the ranking on google search and i loose visitors due to this drop of ranking.

Comment: Thank you . This solution works only for http and its not working for https! Now content wich is requested on my xml api is not loaded "Mixed Content: The page at 'mydomain' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'domain/xml.php'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: That rewriting rule is competely independent from the protocol used to access the URL. http and https hosts are completely separate from the point of view of the http server. So you have separate host configurations. It might be that you implemented the rule at a location only considered by the http host, but that is something I cannot help with, since only you have access to and knowledge about your setup.